# Tkinter throws exception, but the code still works, why?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am working on a comic book reader and my code so far seems to be working great, except for a small result that happens when I update my canvas to display a jpg of the page of the comic book.

The Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, Tcl
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from pyunpack import Archive
import shutil
import tempfile
import os

def open_comic():
    os.mkdir('tmp/')
    text_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open Comic Book File", filetypes=(("CBR Files", "*.cbr"), ("CBZ Files", "*.cbz"), ))
    tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp(suffix='.tmp', dir='tmp/')
    print('Created temp directory', tempdir)
    Archive(text_file).extractall(tempdir)
    file_list = os.listdir(tempdir)
    file_list.sort()
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(tempdir + "/" + file_list[1]))
    my_image = comic_canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=img)
    canvas.update()

# Create the Main Window of the Application
mainWindow = Tk()
mainWindow.title("Comic Reader")
mainWindow.geometry("1200x1500")
buttonFrame = LabelFrame(mainWindow)
canvasFrame = LabelFrame(mainWindow, bg="light gray", border=2)
statusFrame = LabelFrame(mainWindow, bg="black", border=2)
comic_canvas = Canvas(canvasFrame, width="1100", height="1400", bg="light gray")

# Create the Menu Bar for the Application
main_menu = Menu(mainWindow)
mainWindow.config(menu=main_menu)

# The File Menu
file_menu = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=False)
main_menu.add_cascade(menu=file_menu, label="File")
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_comic)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Quit", command=quit_it)

# The Edit Menu
edit_menu = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=False)
main_menu.add_cascade(menu=edit_menu, label="Edit")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Cut", accelerator="(CTRL+X)")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Copy", accelerator="(CTRL+C)") 
edit_menu.add_command(label="Paste", accelerator="(CTRL+V)")

button_back = Button(buttonFrame, text="<=", command=back)
button_exit = Button(buttonFrame, text="Exit", command=quit_it)
button_next = Button(buttonFrame, text="=>", command=lambda: forward(2))

buttonFrame.pack()
canvasFrame.pack()
statusFrame.pack()

button_back.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_exit.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_next.grid(row=1, column=2)
comic_canvas.grid(row=2, column=1)

# Start the Application Here
mainWindow.mainloop()  # Creates the GUI for the Application
```

Now as it is above, it works to update the canvas, and lets you see the image, but throws the error:

```
> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py",
> line 1884, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)   File "/Users/kb2mob/Python Projects/Comic Reader/comicreader.py", line 28, in open_comic
>     canvas.update() NameError: name 'canvas' is not defined
```

Which, yeah it should because the canvas is named "comic_canvas". But then I do use the correct name for the .update() method, it flashes quickly and then vanishes, and of course doesn't throw an error because it's the correct use.

Does anyone know why that is?

This is in Python 3.9.1 on a latest Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

Wasn't keeping the image reference at the end of my function open_comic()

```
comic_canvas.img = img
```

dropped that on the end of it and it worked.